# How to set flags and usage glnamedBufferStorage in new OpenGL 4.4+ (GL_STATIC_DRAW)?

Tags: opengl

In [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferStorage.xhtml) I see that the final parameter for `glNamedBufferStorage` is `flags` and that `flags`:

> Specifies the intended usage of the buffer's data store. Must be a bitwise combination of the following flags. GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT, GL_MAP_READ_BIT GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT, GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT, GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT, and GL_CLIENT_STORAGE_BIT.

However, in the older `glBufferData` we use to specify a `usage` flag which would include things such as `GL_STATIC_DRAW` to specify expected usage patterns.

Where do we include that with the newer OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage flag in BufferData was basically useless. There is no functional difference between each value and drivers used other ways to decide how to handle its data.

The `flags` parameter on the other hand actually changes what you can do with the buffer.